# Keep default value and pass it on

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following piece of code to grab the value of a drop down list. The problem I have is that due to the onchange event attribute the first value is not passed if a user does not select an option. Is there a way I can define when there is no change the first value is passed on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo GetSelectOptionData</title>

<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" onchange="getSelectedValue();">
    <option value="aaaaaaaaa.xml">Text 1</option>
    <option value="bbbbbbbbb.xml">Text 2</option>
</select>

<form action="test">
    Value1: <input id="myField" type="text"  value=""><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSelectedValue() {
     var value = document.getElementById('mySelect').value.split('.');
    document.getElementById('myField').value = value[0];
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Why is your select outside of the form?

Comment: Why not call `getSelectedValue()` on page load too?

Comment: why not set the first option as selected default ? `selected="selected"`

Comment: @j08691 Because its an example, which is way more complex in reality and this is how it is requested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the first option as selected default

```
<option selected="selected" ...
```

and call getSelectedValue() after everything is defined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSelectedValue() {
     var value = document.getElementById('mySelect').value.split('.');
    document.getElementById('myField').value = value[0];
}
getSelectedValue()
</script>
```